# Why does my button calls a function before I click on it?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want my function to be executed after the button press. But as I run the program the button calls the function for all the buttons before I click on them. And when I press the button, after my output is showing, none of the buttons work.

Rest of the buttons in the programs are working fine in the same way.

```
#all the buttons calling the same function buttonEntry(num) with different parameters

button1 = Button(frame_bottom, text="1", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=buttonEntry("1"))
button2 = Button(frame_bottom, text="2", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=buttonEntry("2"))
button3 = Button(frame_bottom, text="3", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=buttonEntry("3"))
button4 = Button(frame_bottom, text="4", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=buttonEntry("4"))
button5 = Button(frame_bottom, text="5", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=buttonEntry("5"))
button6 = Button(frame_bottom, text="6", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=buttonEntry("6"))
button7 = Button(frame_bottom, text="7", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=buttonEntry("7"))
button8 = Button(frame_bottom, text="8", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=buttonEntry("8"))
button9 = Button(frame_bottom, text="9", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=buttonEntry("9"))
button0 = Button(frame_bottom, text="0", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=buttonEntry("0"))

#function which doesn't execute when button is pressed
def buttonEntry(num):
    n=num
    print(n)
```

I want 1 to be displayed when button1 is pressed, 2 to be displayed when button2 is pressed, so, on. But when I run the program, all the buttons run their commands at once and shows the output like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And the button pressed afterward doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your aren't actually passing the function as the callback, you are passing the return value. To fix this, add `lambda:` before everything:

```
button1 = Button(frame_bottom, text="1", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=lambda: buttonEntry("1"))
button2 = Button(frame_bottom, text="2", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=lambda: buttonEntry("2"))
```

And so on.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it would be that simple

Answer (score 0):

The Button widget takes a callback function as its last argument, which would be called when the button is clicked. However, you are passing in `buttonEntry("1")`, which is `None`, since calling the `buttonEntry` function like that will set a local variable called `n` to be `num` and then prints `num`, but doesn't return anything, i.e. `None`.

If you want the function to be called when you click a button, you need to pass the function itself, not the result:

```
button1 = Button(frame_bottom, text="1", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=buttonEntry)
```

Of course, that way, the callback won't know which button was called, as all of them would be calling `buttonEntry()`. So, instead of providing the function as a callback directly, you can make a lambda function that will get called, which then calls the `buttonEntry` function with the right value:

```
button1 = Button(frame_bottom, text="1", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=lambda: buttonEntry("1"))
```

Read more about functions, return values and `lambda` if you want to understand more about why this works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you're setting the command for each button:

```
command=buttonEntry("1")
```

Because `buttonEntry` is a function, it is called at this point, which prints the number and assigns `None` to command.

`command` is also expecting a callable here. What you need to do is create a factory that creates functions that return the expected value, then update your `Button` setup:

```
def buttonEntryFactory(num):
    def buttonEntry():
        print num
    return buttonEntry

button1 = Button(frame_bottom, text="1", width="20", height="6", bg=buttonColor, command=buttonEntryFactory("1"))
```

Now, when you define the button, it creates a specific `buttonEntry` function for it with the correct value enclosed and assigns that function to `command`. When you click on the button, it will then call the function as expected.

In summary: `command` expects to be given a function (or callable) as an argument, so if you want to add custom parameters for commands, you'll need to use a factory to create a function with those parameters contained inside. (The other alternative is to use a `lambda`, but I find the factory approach a little cleaner).